# Create a list based on checkbox items being selected

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have a list of checkboxes with different values that then will populate into a multi-line textbox based on the selection. I will need to have the list be dynamic between users checking and unchecking boxes and having these populate by their selection into this textbox.

[image]

Any direction will help thanks!

I do not have a solution for this aright now

Answer (score 0):

You can list multiple controls after the "Handles" keyword in an event handler. In this case, we want to handle the CheckChanged event of your CheckBoxes. Note the multiple `ControlName.Event` entries separated by commas after "Handles":

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub AnyCheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged,
            CheckBox4.CheckedChanged, CheckBox5.CheckedChanged, CheckBox6.CheckedChanged

        Dim cbs() As CheckBox = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4, CheckBox5, CheckBox6}
        Dim values As New List(Of String)
        For Each cb As CheckBox In cbs
            If cb.Checked Then
                values.Add(cb.Text)
            End If
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, values)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Within that handler, that fires when any of the CheckBoxes is changed, I create an Array of the CheckBoxes invovled. Now you can iterate over them in order and add their value to a `List(Of String)` if it is checked. When done, we simply put all the values from the list together separated by newlines and assign the resulting string to the multiline TextBox.

The above should be easy to understand, but here is an alternate approach that keeps the Array at class/form level so it is only created once. Instead of using "Handles" it wires up the events using `AddHandler`. Additionally, it uses LINQ to extract the selected values:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private cbs() As CheckBox

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cbs = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4, CheckBox5, CheckBox6}
        For Each cb As CheckBox In cbs
            AddHandler cb.CheckedChanged, AddressOf AnyCheckBox_CheckedChanged
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub AnyCheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim values = cbs.Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked).Select(Function(cb) cb.Text)
        TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, values)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hi Thank you in advanced I am getting the following error for the first option
"Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types." do you know why this would be pulling this?

Comment: You need to change the names of the checkboxes in my example to those that are actually on your form. Both after the Handles keyword and below in the array declaration. I used CheckBox1, CheckBox2, etc...

Comment: You figure it out Sven? The Handles keyword is designed to be used with variables declared as WithEvents. This is normally done for you when you add controls to the form via the designer, but it can also be done manually via code. If you're using dynamic controls, then you'd use AddHandler instead, more like the second example.

Comment: Hi Yep, I was able to fix the issue I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way of doing this is to create an extended CheckBox class which can then be hooked up to the TextBox. This puts the add/remove logic in the extended class, and no additional code needs to be added to the form.

Create a new Class.

```
Public Class CheckBoxExtended
Inherits CheckBox

Public Property TextBox As TextBox

Public Sub New()
    AddHandler Me.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf CheckStateChangedEventArgs
End Sub

Private Sub CheckStateChangedEventArgs(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If TextBox Is Nothing Then Return
    Select Case CheckState
        Case CheckState.Unchecked
            TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text.Replace($"{Text}{Environment.NewLine}", "")
        Case CheckState.Checked
            TextBox.Text += $"{Text}{Environment.NewLine}"
    End Select
End Sub

End Class
```

After building the project, the new control will be available in the toolbox in the designer. Add them to the form and make sure you hook-up the textbox to the control (in the properties):

[image]

I would however recommend using a ListBox (instead of a TextBox), where you can use the Items collection. This would change the extended class to:

```
Public Class CheckBoxExtended
Inherits CheckBox

Public Property ListBox As ListBox

Public Sub New()
    AddHandler Me.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf CheckStateChangedEventArgs
End Sub

Private Sub CheckStateChangedEventArgs(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If ListBox Is Nothing Then Return
    Select Case CheckState
        Case CheckState.Unchecked
            ListBox.Items.Remove(Text)
        Case CheckState.Checked
            ListBox.Items.Add(Text)
    End Select
End Sub

End Class
```

**Note** that both these approaches have the limitation that the checkbox text must be unique, as it removes all instances of the text.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I am trying to set this up with the first option you recommended as this would need to work in a textbox and can't use a listbox but I am throwing an error:

'CheckStateChanged' is not an event of 'fbd58352743c3246ea82edd4714d608faa.CheckBoxExtended'.

Any idea as to what it maybe I have all controls setup following your initial code?

Comment: Make sure the class is inheriting the CheckBox. Also trying using the full namespace i.e. System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox